# How can I turn on/off "use wireless network" in location settings?

Tags: android

How can I turn on/off "use wireless network" in location settings programatically on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This preference is present in Settings.secure. So you cannot write to such a setting programmatically. This has to be specifically enabled by User. Check the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html)